# SPD 2010: Can fields be hidden by Conditional Formatting on NewForm?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form, list-form, form

I use content types to dynamically change which fields (columns) are initially displayed on the newform page. I am trying to have the fields change *as* the user is filling out the form. I was trying to use the **Conditional Formatting** feature on the newform page to hide fields based on user entry, but having no luck. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Enterprise?

Comment: Not sure, but it's definitely not Foundation. How would I know the difference?

Comment: Normally, you know by checking in Central Administration, it will tell you the version. However, if you don't have access, check by the features that you might have. If you have the ability to create browser based InfoPath forms, you will have enterprise.

Comment: I don't have Central Admin access, but based on the InfoPath availability, I know we are using Enterprise. InfoPath forms are not an option for this unfortunately.

Comment: Customizing your default forms with InfoPath would be the easiest solution for this, because you can use conditional formatting easily with that. Not sure of another way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,
see the following post - http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=3

if you don't want to hassle with SP designer - use this free tool - http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartListLite

Answer (score 0):

Sure.... You can hide a control in InfoPath.. Open the New Form in InfoPath... Manage rules>>>Click new>>>formatting>>>mention your conditions and then click the option *Hide this control* shown below.

Comment: I don't have InfoPath. Is this possible with SP Designer only?

Comment: Decided to give in and purchase an InfoPath license. Thanks for the info, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Yeap. This is one way to hide the fields. I use it all the time. This is good if you are hiding field B because field A was not populated. However it's a nightmare if you are trying to hide a field based on user's SP Groups. Meaning, if the current user belong to one sp group A she/he will only see Field A, if the current user belong to SPGroup B then she/he will only see Field B and C. You would use userGroup.asmx web services with groupcollectionbyuser method. Hope it helps. It depends what is the condition that makes a filed hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via JQuery.

1. Add [JQuery to SharePoint](http://www.nerdyhearn.com/blog/193).
2. Create [a custome new item form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010378258.aspx).
3. Add a Form webpart.
4. Open the custom new form in code view.
5. In the
    you wish to hide give them IDs and hide them via inline styles
   if you need to like
6. Use a JQuery script to attach
   [events](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/03/working-with-events-part-1) to the controls and hide and display the table rows you
   need to using the [HTML visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) property.

I've used this approach on several occasions and is a great way to add color coding, display/hide fields, and add form validation in conjunction with [PreSaveAction](http://replicrux.com/2011/11/09/validating-forms-in-sharepoint.aspx).