# Field-Level Security

Tags: 2010, security

Is it possible to set up field-level security on list columns for both visibility and modification out of the box, or leveraging out-of-the-box methods **without customized InfoPath forms or custom-coded items** (because we do not have InfoPath available to us, nor do we have anyone with the custom-coding experience needed)?

Answer (score 1):

No, but there are several paid for and free tools available to do this.

**Update:**

here are a few links:

1. http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/  This one is free but needs some modification to work in SP 2010 (see here:  http://somesharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/06/faire-fonctionner-splistdisplaysetting.html)
2. http://datapolis.com/Products/SharePointColumnProtector.aspx
3. http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx

Comment: Not an option, those'd need vetting and security analysis by ITSec here.  We need to do this out of the box, and without InfoPath or custom code.  Are you absolutely certain there is no method to do this *without* InfoPath or custom coding?

Comment: Having said this, can you provide some links to such "paid or free" tools, in case the project manager wants to look into acquiring the tools

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using SharePoint designer or Jquery. This may be helpful : [SPD 2010: Can fields be hidden by Conditional Formatting on NewForm?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22235/spdesigner-2010-can-fields-be-hidden-by-conditional-formatting-on-newform)

And also this one  : http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3

Please note that the above ways don't provide any server side security but just hide the columns only in UI.

Comment: Will this work on the form(s) for editing, without customization?

Comment: You will need to do it by SharePoint designer.

Comment: I've got SPD, so that's not a huge problem. Thanks.  I'll tackle these, and mark your answer as the correct one when it works.

Comment: Be aware that any solution which doesn't put the secured columns into a different list with different permissions are only going to be information hiding not security.

Comment: Just remember, custom infopath forms dont tend to respect column or field level security that impose by the Codeplex tool. You need to ask bamboo to make sure field security will work with custom forms.

Comment: UI-level hiding is the goal here, server/db-side security isnt a requirement, we just dont need people who don't have edit permissions on certain fields to edit those fields.  And did I meniton InfoPath isnt an option here?

Answer (score 0):

I personally used this one from codeplex and worked per our requirements where HR wanted to hide some confidential columns based on SharePoint user groups.

http://sppex.codeplex.com/

However, for certain cases where I had to implement custom infopath form the security did not kick in.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not support column level security，you have these alternative methods to implement this feature：

Free tools:

- http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/
- http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/

Paid tools with free trial:

- http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html
- http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-list-forms-extensions-feature/overview/