# Conditional Columns in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column, conditional

Is there a way to have a Conditional Column with Multi-Line Text that will only show up in the list if a certain status is selected?

Comment: This is not possible using OOTB features.

Answer (score 0):

I do not personally know how to accomplish this task BUT I did find the following links from past posts that could assist:

[SPD 2010: Can fields be hidden by Conditional Formatting on NewForm?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22235/spd-2010-can-fields-be-hidden-by-conditional-formatting-on-newform)

This one may also help out :)

[SharePoint designer conditional formatting to hide column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b65fe5a1-1d12-47d2-ab62-10f62f654456/sharepoint-designer-conditional-formatting-to-hide-column?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

And a third. [Hide fields on sharepoint custom list form, No code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37840/hide-fields-on-sharepoint-custom-list-form-no-code)

I am quite new to the SharePoint SE as well but... Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The only OOTB way that I know of to do this is to have to create a list content type for each of your status values, and include the column in only one of the content types.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Create a flow in *Power Automate* by applying a **condition on the trigger**, if the condition is satisfied then fill the column.